# How to turn iOS device display completely off?

Tags: ios, swift

We are currently developing an iOS application which we need to run in Single App Mode with device lock deactivated. What we would like to have is that the screen turns completely dark and as soon as there is a socket/mqtt event or a touch event the display should brighten up.

Everything works so far the only thing that is not perfect is that the display doesn't turn completely off using:

```
UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.0)
```

Is there a way on how we could achieve that?

Comment: Well, that's the minimum brightness. What comes on my mind is to set modal view that has a black background and when you get info from socket event, just set the background white and set brightness to desired constant?

Comment: Or, set overlay UIView that will disappear with animation where you set new brightness in completion block.

Comment: Just as a note, I have a mode in my app that does this and the backlight being mostly off and nothing pegging the processor it runs for very long time. I do however suggest subscribing to battery notifications so you can have it quit out if its not plugged in and under a certain threshold.

Comment: Hi solenoid
Thanks a lot for your feedback. In my app I am doing nothing else than keep a MQTT connection open. The battery drains to 50% within 8 hours. That seems to be to much for me. Any other ideas on how I could improve that?

Comment: Hi Stefan
Sounds interesting, but I didn't get how that should exactly look like? Could you provide me some more details?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no current way to do it.

Without a jailbreak there is no actual way to turn of the screen. And even mimmiking the screen turn off like you are doing now will propably get your app rejected.

The reason is that even if the pixel is black, the screen backlight is still on in LED displays.

PS: The new iPhone 8 is said to come with OLED display (if it turned out to be true). The oled screen shuts down the light of the pixel when it is black unlike the current screen (OLED have independednt light for each pixel unlike LED that's why it turns off). Thus your code will work perfectly on iphone 8. This is a hardware change not a software change thus you cant adapt it in your code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve "locked" screen effect, I would recommend adding `UIView` as subview of your `UIViewController` that will take whole screen. That `UIView` should have black background and minimum brightness set. When you get event from the socket, just animate `UIView` disappearing with setting brightness to desired constant.

Example when you get event:

```
overlayView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: SCREEN_HEIGHT)
vc.addSubview(overlayView)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
    self.overlayView?.removeFromSuperview

}, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
    UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.8)
})
```

I'm writing this answer without helping of compiler so please do not mind me if there's some syntax error. This is only draft.

Comment: Hi Stefan
Thanks for the idea. It is what I implemented this morning. But the thing is that it still drains more battery than if the display would be off, correct? Its just that the user doesnt notice it? Is there anything else that could be turned/switched off to save battery?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought you need only interface-oriented solution. I didn't investigate optimization solutions for this.